# Sendmail's maillog polluted by dkim-filter

Tags: linux, redhat, sendmail, log-files, dkim

I just added domain keys to my sendmail configuration and everything appears to be working.  However, upon reviewing the maillog I get a ton of these when an email gets sent or received:

```
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
Oct  4 09:42:44 servername sendmail[22036]: q94GgiGB022036: milter=dkim-filter, action=header, continue
```

Any clues as to what might be causing this?  It's not a huge issue but I'd rather not have that many lines every time one email gets sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dkim-filter` has a -l option. If you omit that argument chances are that these log lines will disappear.

Another possible way is installing `syslog-ng` and using filtering directives you can remove lines before they gets logged. (I like the latter as you can remove other programs meaningless output too.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I'll look into both options.  Is this normal functionality?  Do you know why it's logging so many duplicate messages like this?

Comment: I guess that after each intercepted header you get a log line as the daemon is in verbose mode. I might be wrong as I am not familiar with sendmail, but I use dkim-filter with postfix.